# Flutter make a sound on button press

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I want to make a sound when the button is pressed in Flutter. The codes don't give an error but make no sound. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AudioCache()` class like this

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void playSound(int soundNumber) {
  final player = AudioCache();
  player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Xylophone'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
                child: Text(''),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```